# Do three finger navigation gestures work in System Preferences?

Tags: system-settings, multi-touch

I've been playing around with a lot of different settings, and I'm not sure if one of the changes I made causes three finger gestures to not work in the System Preferences application, or if they never worked in the app to begin with.

When you navigate through the application and the forward or back buttons are enabled, does using the three finger swipe advance you forward or backward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unfortunately three-finger swipes do not work in System Preferences.